# Keep input box in view on click (block expand)

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have the following JavaScript for a CSS table that hides and displays content on click:

```
function toggle2(id, link) {
 var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == '') {
   e.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
   e.style.display = '';
  }
}
```

Then I have the following code to display an input box under "question":

```
<li>
  <a href="#" onclick="toggle2(\'question\', this);">Question
   <div id="question" style="display:none; margin:0px;">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

the problem is, when I click the **input box** which I need to keep in the `block`, the **box** goes away. I need that **box** to stay, how can I achieve this without affecting the other stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you click the input box, you also "click" the `<a>`. Move it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/d33zC/

Notice the `display:inline-block` on the `<div>` if you want the input box to stay in one line with the link.

**Edit**:

Extending from comment, it seems this is what you're looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/d33zC/5/

Move `border-bottom` from `a` to `li`.

Comment: hmm, we want it to say Question (as a link), that is clicked, and the input box appears below it, but we need the <li> below it to move too

Comment: @mobile The link _will_ be moved down by default: http://jsfiddle.net/d33zC/1/ Is there any style applied on your `<li>`?

Comment: we're using the 2nd example on this page if it helps: http://css-tricks.com/examples/OrganicTabsReplaceState/?tab=featured2

Comment: @mobile Are you saying that you're using `<li>` as tabs? It has a fixed width (97px), so the other tabs would not be "push". Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/d33zC/2/

Comment: Sorry, I've not explained well, on the link i posted, i'm talking about the content of the tabbed box, not the tab itself, you'll see they are all links, looking to have one as "question" that you can click and have it expand, while keeping the others as linkable, if that makes sense!

Comment: @mobile If you are only talking about the content, it _should_ push below content down, as there's no special styling on the `<li>`. Is your _actual_ code styling `<li>` to, for example, a fixed `height`?

Comment: this is the code for the link list: http://pastie.org/private/amzagfewezhukltbklsecw

Comment: @mobile Applied your code and still not thing wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/d33zC/3/ The `<li>` will be pushed down.

Comment: Ah, you can see there that the input box appears _below_ the line in the link list, which doesn't look right for a question area above a link, because the box "goes into" link below

Comment: @mobile That's because it's the `<a>` that has the border. Is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/d33zC/5/ ?

Comment: That is perfect! Have I told you that I love you?

Comment: Managed to get the border and margin sized down to fit the list, but the tabs at the top have an underline, can they be removed?

Comment: @mobile You can overwrite them in `.nav` styles: `.nav li { width: 97px; float: left; margin: 0 10px 0 0; border:none; }`.

Comment: @mobile Where's `border:none` in your new pastie?

Comment: Just realised that i had two similar lines going. All working good now, thankyou!

Comment: @mobile You **should** add the rule to `#example-two .nav li` instead of make a new one at the top. Later rule overwrites earlier ones, so `#example-two li` will overwrite your first `#example-two .nav li` in this order.

Answer (score 0):

The input box gets hidden because it is within the `question` div.  Move it outside and you would not have the problem.

Comment: If it's moved outside the <a> tag, it goes under the line, conflicting with the box beneath it

Comment: @mobile it is all about the CSS styles that you need, but that's how it needs to be done for not hiding the `input` element.

Comment: Not sure how to apply this to a bunch of <li>s that need to be beneath each other, to give you an idea its the 2nd example here we're using http://css-tricks.com/examples/OrganicTabsReplaceState/?tab=featured2